# Css Wrapper and Container Div Auto Height?

Tags: html, css

I want div in div height set auto.

http://bit.ly/rubikss1

at the bottom of the div inside is coming out. I want the bottom div to extend to.

Please Help!

```css
body,html{height:100%}

.wrapper{
 width: 700px;
        height: 100%;
 margin: 25px auto;
        overflow:hidden;
        position: relative;
}

.inner-container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 position: relative;
}

.button-container{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 35px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}

#prev, #next{
 border: 0;
 background: #5CB85C;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#next{
 float: right;
}

#prev{
 float: left;
}

#verilistesi{
 float: left;
 width: 700px;
        height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#verilistesi .item-container{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

#verilistesi .item-container .item{
 width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

My css.

How i do set auto height two div? Please give help?

Comment: Your question is not ver clear... but try removing the 100% height from the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you want:

```
        body,html{height:100%}

        .wrapper{
            width: 700px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 25px auto;
            overflow:hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .inner-container{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
            position: relative;
        }

        .button-container{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: 35px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #prev, #next{
            border: 0;
            background: #5CB85C;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #next{
            float: right;
        }

        #prev{
            float: left;
        }

        #verilistesi{
            float: left;
            width: 700px;
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #verilistesi .item-container{
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }

        #verilistesi .item-container .item{
            width: 500px;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            margin-bottom: 35px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```